# C Printf won't print certain 0s

Tags: c

A program I am working on for a school project ignores 0s when printing. For example, this function would not print the first arm (Arm 0) so I added an extra printf before the for loop but whenever my armArray[i].count is equal to 0 it ignores it like this:

```
Total Payoff: 75.67
Arm   Count   Avg. Payoff   Value
  0       3         -0.02    0.59
  1      74          0.94    0.86
  2      19          0.25    0.18
  3       4          0.33    0.89
  4                  0.00    0.25
```

```
void PrintStatistics(const BanditArm armArray[], int numArms) {
    double tPayoff = 0.0;
    for(int i =0; i<numArms;i++){
        tPayoff+=armArray[i].totalPayoff;
    }
    printf("Total Payoff:%6.2f\n",tPayoff);
    printf("Arm   Count   Avg. Payoff   Value\n");
    printf("  0%8.0d%14.2f%8.2lf\n",armArray[0].count,armArray[0].avgPayoff,armArray[0].payoffMean);
    for(int i =1; i<numArms;i++){
        if(armArray[i].count==0)
        printf("%3d%8.0d%14.2f%8.2lf\n",i,0,armArray[i].avgPayoff,armArray[i].payoffMean);
        else
        printf("%3d%8.0d%14.2f%8.2lf\n",i,armArray[i].count,armArray[i].avgPayoff,armArray[i].payoffMean);
    }
}
```

If more of the code is needed I can add the rest.

Comment: What 0s are ignored? What does it mean?

Comment: change `for(int i =1...` to `for(int i=0...`

Comment: Change `%8.0d` to `%8d`. `printf` is just doing what you asked it to do.

Comment: Refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%3d%8.0d%14.2f%8.2lf\n",i,0,armArray[i].avgPayoff,armArray[i].payoffMean);
```

The second format specifier `%8.0d` provides a precision of `0`. For `%d` the precision gives the minimum number of digits to appear. Since you gave `0` precision it means nothing will be printed for 0 values. There is no need for the precision in this case. So either remove it completely or give a precision of 1.

That is, `%8d` or `%8.1d`.

As a side note, you don't really need to have that last `if/else` condition. The `printf` in the `else` case is sufficient for both the zero and non-zero cases.

Comment: Thank you! And that last if/else statement was my attempt to try and fix it but changing the precision fixed it and I removed it.

Comment: You should also not need the extra `printf` at the beginning. Should be able to start the `for` loop from `0`. I guess you were trying to work around some issue but it is better to fix that properly rather than work around it. Post a new question if you can't work that out.